# Random color game, array and input

Tags: java

So I am having some trouble. I cant seem to figure out my issue with assigning my random color(see the commented out section). Also any advice as to how to remove the text from the previous question when it is answered correctly? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Game Driver Class

```
public class MemoryGame {

public static void main(String[] args) {

   Questions q = new Questions();


   }
}
```

---

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Random;

public class Questions{

Random r = new Random();

private JFrame mainwindow;
private JLabel label1;
private JTextField txtQ1;
int num = 1;
String[] solution = new String[5];
String[] colors = {"red","green","blue","yellow","brown","black","purple","white","orange","grey"};

//for (int i = 0; i < solution.length; i++)
// {
//    solution[i] = colors[r.nextInt(10)];
//}


public Questions()
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"How good is your memory?\nTry to memorize this color sequence:\n"+solution);

    createContents();

    mainwindow.setVisible(true);
}

private void createContents()
{
    mainwindow = new JFrame();
    mainwindow.setSize(600, 400);
    mainwindow.setTitle("Memory Game");
    mainwindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(mainwindow.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    mainwindow.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    label1 = new JLabel();
    txtQ1 = new JTextField(15);
    label1.setText("Enter color number: "+num);

    //Add Action to text box
    txtQ1.addActionListener(new QuestionListener());

    mainwindow.add(label1);
    mainwindow.add(txtQ1);


}

public class QuestionListener implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e)
    {


        String guess = "";

        guess = txtQ1.getText();

        if (colors[num-1].equalsIgnoreCase(guess))
        {
            System.out.println("Congratulations continue to next question.");
            num++;

            label1.setText("Enter color number: "+num);
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Sorry wrong color.");
        }

        if (num == 6)
        {
            label1.setText("Congratulations, Your memory is perfect");
            txtQ1.setVisible(false);
        }


    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put that loop in a method or in the constructor. Something like:

```
public Questions()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < solution.length; i++)
    {
        solution[i] = colors[r.nextInt(10)];
    }

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"How good is your memory?\nTry to memorize this color sequence:\n"+solution);

    createContents();

    mainwindow.setVisible(true);
}
```

Also you may want to use

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"How good is your memory?\nTry to memorize this color sequence:\n" + Arrays.toString(solution));
```

Comment: Thank you the first solution worked however i get a cannot find symbol error when I add the Arrays.toString.

Comment: Make sure you import `java.util.Arrays`. Which IDE do you use? Normally that should've been taken care of for you or at least it should have allowed you to click the line/error and import or something like that.

Comment: I normally use IntelliJ but I am using Jgrasp and the moment. Its not very good.Thank you for your help! I'm just realizing I had a few more issues than I though.